# Make bootstrap input on horizontal form absolute positioned without affecting width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a horizontal bootstrap form and need a `<input>` absolute positioned for reasons too boring to explain. However, I'm battling getting it the same width as it used to be prior to absolute. So in the linked example, I want the password field to be the same width as the email field.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 400px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control abs" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.abs {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; /* 100%; */
}
```

How can I modify this fiddle?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8aco78L7/1/)

Comment: Why are you using width: inherit; ?

Comment: I just left it that way in the fiddle. I got desperate and tried a bunch of stuff.

Comment: I tried but the problem is still there, the password field is `30px` wider.

I can relate this to the `padding-right:15px` `padding-left: 15px` from bootstrap.

Comment: Below answer gives me this: it works :) try to put  -    .abs {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 400px;
    }

Comment: Position absolute takes the element out of the regular document flow. You need to include input {max-width: 400px;} in your CSS, same width as for the form-group. Remove the width: inherit for the password field.

Comment: I think I figured it out. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Louis' answer as inspiration, I think I was able to simplify this a little bit.

```
.abs-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Seems to work fine regardless of width of the form as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/8aco78L7/4/

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do it, although it does require a few divs.
The idea is to not apply the `position: absolute` property to the input element itself but to a container which has the same structure as the form. This way, we can be certain they will both always share the same size.

```css
.password-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.password-container > .form-horizontal {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 400px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="password-container">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2"> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control abs" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Since it only uses `divs` semantics is not affected.

Comment: You're very welcome, your solution is definitely better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-sm-10 {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width: 400px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control abs" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This only appears to work when the horizontal form is collapsed. Expand into full page.